# Connecting to a SQL server whose IP changes

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to connect to a server whose `IP` is dynamic via a VB.net application.
 I have configured the connection string in my VB application to a static IP. 
I also gave a static `IP` to the database.

However, this work-around can be dangerous. Can someone please suggest an **efficient way to connect to a `SQL` server in a remote machine whose `IP` is dynamic**.

Comment: Is there any reason not to connect to it's hostname?

Comment: I didn't try that. If the computers all connected to the network, then is it possible to connect to a server remotely just by its hostname? :)

Comment: Yes. See Sporri's answer.

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way to connect to a server is to use it's hostname and not an IP address. The local DHCP should be updating the DNS records so connecting to a hostname should always work, if not talk to the people configuring your network.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse proxy app such as ScaleArc, Dell's/Quest's new solution for Oracle scale out that they just ported to SQL Server, DDNS, hostfile entries, or just raw IPs.  What is dangerous about raw IPs?  Are you worried they might change?

Comment: Yes, actually the server should get the IP from the DHCP ideally. Is it possible to put the physical address of the machine somehow instead of the IP?

Comment: Quick question, is why is your production server on DHCP 'ideally'?  That's almost never ever ideal.  Even in cases where you can't change the IP range for DHCP, you can reserve an IP.  If it's going to be DHCP you will have the chance of a IP change, then DDNS would need to be used and updated.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating an alias for the application to connect to?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190445(v=sql.105).aspx

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1620/how-to-setup-and-use-a-sql-server-alias/